# How to activate storyboard only once instead of all elements of User Control (Silverlight + Expression Blend)

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, expression-blend

I created a User Control that has an image, text, and description. I would like to animate it to display a border when user hovers over. 
I have done that, but the animation fires off on each element of the control so the border keeps on appearing and disappearing again.

Here is the code for my control. 
Please help and thank you in advance!

```
    <UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.CommandLinks"
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480" Width="280" Cursor="Hand">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="CommandLinksMounseOver">
        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="#FFB0D0E0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="brdBorder" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="brdBorder" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="-1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="brdBorder" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="CommandLinksMouseOut">
        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="#FFD9E8F0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="brdBorder" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="-1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="brdBorder" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.1" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="brdBorder" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction x:Name="OnMouseOut" Storyboard="{StaticResource CommandLinksMouseOut}"/>
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction x:Name="OnMouseOver" Storyboard="{StaticResource CommandLinksMounseOver}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Border x:Name="brdBorder" Margin="0" CornerRadius="3" BorderThickness="1" Padding="8" BorderBrush="#00B3D1E1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Grid>
            <Image x:Name="imgIcon" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="32" Margin="0" Source="Universal Binary.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="32">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform/>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
            </Image>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtMainInstruction" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Main instruction text" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="0" Foreground="#FF2C5A88" FontSize="13.333" FontFamily="Verdana" Margin="40,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform/>
                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtDescription" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Enter the description here if needed" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF666666" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Verdana" Margin="40,20,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform/>
                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You have specified a lighter blue when mouse leaves, so there will always be a border there, is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Along with setting a transparent background (I put it on the brdBorder element) as already suggested there is a problem with your triggers. They should look like this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction x:Name="OnMouseOut" Storyboard="{StaticResource CommandLinksMouseOut}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction x:Name="OnMouseOver" Storyboard="{StaticResource CommandLinksMounseOver}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks Bill! Yes, I just looked at my code and I have fixed that already. My looks now exactly like yours does. I still have an issue where the trigger fires off on every element of the user control (both text boxes, image, and border) and I need it to be only fired once when my mouse enters the entire control. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you put Background="Transparent" on the brdBorder? Once I did that it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The control has no background. Therefore only the text and the image are hit test visible. Try Background="#00000000" (transparent) on the LayoutRoot.

Comment: My background is of that color so I added it (otherwise when border was added, all other items that are in wrap panel were jumping down a little big to accommodate for the border). I will fix the border to be transparent, thanks! 

My problem is still with storyboard. As I hover over, it shows when mouse goes over the border then disappears. Shows again when I am over an image, then hides again and same with two text boxes. I need to to activate only once as I am inside the control and hide the border as I leave the control. Please help!